# Fitting length of finite groups of order $p^a.q^b$?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

While studying the structure of groups of order $p^a.q^b$, I may have proved that the Fitting length of such group (which is always solvable by Burnside Theorem) is at much 2 when max$(a,b) \leq$ min$(p,q)$. Since I encounter some (hopefully minor) technical difficulties, I am not fully sure of the result.

If true, the result would be interesting since it has the corrolary that for fixed $a$ and $b$, all groups of order $p^a.q^b$ are meta-nilpotent with a finite list of exceptions.

I would like to know if it has already been proven somewhere, a reference would be appreciated.

In case my reasonning is wrong and result is false, would you have a counter-example?

As suggested by D. Holt, I add to my question the sketch of the "proof".

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^a.q^b$ with Fitting length at least three. Relying on the Fitting chain, up to exchanging the roles of $p$ and $q$, there exists a subquotient $H$ of $G$ which has the following structure: a characteristic (thus normal) subgoup $F_p$, a quotient $H/F_p$ of the form
$G_q:C_p$ and an action by conjugation of $G_q$ on $F_p$ with a trivial kernel.

In a $p$-group, the quotient by the Frattini subgroup is an abelian group with all elements of order 1 or $p$, which is thus isomorphic to a finite dimension vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Furthermore all outer automorphisms of order coprime to $p$ induces a nontrivial linear transformation of this vector field.

In the above setting we have a faithfull representation of $G_q$ in $\mathrm{GL}_u(\mathbb{F}_p)$ where $u$ is the dimension as a $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space of $F_p/\Phi(F_p)$. Here comes the part where I am less comfortable with. By Maschke theorem, the linear representation of $G_q$ is the reduction mod $p$ of linear representation over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let us consider first the case where $G_q$ is not abelian. A faithful representation cannot be a sum of representations of dimension 1. Since $G_q$ is q-group, the irreducible representations must have dimension a power of $q$, so it is at least $q$ for one of them and the initial representation lives in dimension at least $q$.

In the case where $G_q$ is abelian, the representation is a direct sum of representations of dimension 1 (potentially after tensoring with a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$). The group $C_p$ acts faithfully on $G_q$ so it acts faithfully on his dual and this action results in a permutation of dimension 1 representations. An orbit is of length 1 or $p$ and all orbits cannot be trivial. A such, the initial representation is of dimension at least $p$.

Combining both cases, we have that the dimension $u$ of the linear representation is either at least $p$ or at least $q$, so we have $u\geq \mathrm{min}(p,q)$. We also have $a\geq u+1$, which yields $a \geq \mathrm{min}(p,q)+1$. At the beginning, we did choose roles for $p$ and $q$ that may be reversed. In this case, the result would have been $b \geq \mathrm{min}(p,q)+1$. So the final result is $\mathrm{max}(a,b) \geq \mathrm{min}(p,q)+1$.

Comment: This result sounds very plausible to me. I don't know whether it has been proved already.  All I can suggest is that you write out the proof here and indicate the places where you are uncertain, and include the solution-verification tag. Alternatively, you could try and isolate the claims in the proof that you are unsure of, and ask about them individually.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I edited the question to include the sketch of the "proof".

Comment: I can't see any immedaiet flaws in your reasoning, but I will look at it more carefully later. What is $H_q$? Is $H_q=G_q$?

Comment: $F_p$ is the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $F(G)$ and $G_q$ is the $q$-Sylow subgroup of $F(G/F(G))$. It is well known that the Fitting subgroup is self-centralizing, meaning that $G_q$ acts faithfully on $F(G)$ but one can show a bit more: $G_q$ acts faithfully on $F_p$. My apologies, I used inconsistent notations but I corrected it in the initial question.

Comment: I think the proof is fine. I am unsure exactly which step you are uncertain about.

Comment: The steps I am uncertain about are the claims that representations of $G_p$ over $\mathbb{F}(p)$ are in a certain sense reduction mod $p$ of its representations over $\mathbb{C}$. Furthermore, if $q$ does not divide $p-1$, there is a need to consider finite extensions of $\mathbb{F}(p)$, which I did not make explicit. If you know some litterature (accessible freely online) that cover this topic, that would help me to clean-up the proof. I would also like to know if the result is of any interest for group theorist, in which case I could try to publish on Arxiv if I manage to get a clean proof.

Comment: Let $G_q$ be a finite group with order not divisible by a prime $p$ and let $V$ be an ${\mathbb F}_pG_q$-module. For any extension field $K$ of ${\mathbb F}_p$, the tensor product $V_K := K \otimes_{{\mathbb F}_p} V$ is a $KG$-module of the same dimension. In your situation you could take $K$ to be a splitting field for $G_q$ in characteristic $p$, or if you prefer the algebraic closure of ${\mathbb F}_p$. Now you can apply your arguments to $V_K$ and deduce lower bounds on its dimension, which apply also to $V$.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will need to read more about such modules and tensor products since I feel those are exactly the tools I need.